# What should I be buying in the Magic Shop?

Tags: summoners-war

The Magic Shop offers random loot that refreshes every hour.

What should I be spending my Mana Stones on or what items are good to look out for? I currently don't need any of the runes it's offering me and I don't find that buying 1-3 Summoning Scrolls is worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appreciated items in the magic store are mystical scrolls. These are quite rare, and the quality of shop items will increase with your level.

Sometimes you'll also have the luck of seeing some good runes in the store, which are worth their price.

There are also some monsters worth buying, such as :

Ramagos, wind warbear, who is a good monster
Shannon, wind pixie, who is also a very good monster
Coleen, fire harpu, who is a good monster too
The fire imp (Cogma) , who is fusion material
Wind harpu (Seal), who is also fusion material

A recent patch also added legendary pieces and light and dark pieces. I don't recommand using your mana on this early on because you need a lot of pieces before having your scroll.

Answer (score -1):

I just made an experiment, where I refreshed 100 times the magic shop to see what I got. Here's the video:

Comment: Including the video is a good addition to the answer, but could you also include the conclution in your answer's text? We generaly frown upon link-only asnwers.

Comment: I actually really like this answer. I think it has great potential to be better than the accepted one. You'll just need to go into detail about what you found during your trials. Really interesting video though.